# Reponse.Redirect not working when the response from server is very slow asp.net

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

We are using Oracle 11g as backend in our asp.net Web application.

In signup page when user clicks on creates a new account button. Since we are creating sample data for the user on db back end. Its taking nearly 90 secs to run the stored procedure and give response. Here after creating new app account we are redirecting to Thank you page using below code

```
Response.Redirect("../thankyou.aspx",false);
```

But its not redirecting to the Thankyou page

if i comment out create account method on button click the above code working and redirects to Thank you page.

I tried `Server.Transfer("URL")`, `Response.Redirect("URL")` but not working

I donot understand how to solve this issue. Please let me know how to solve this issue....

Comment: 90 min is too mch time for db operations... Since when you comment out db operation redirect works , so  you have no problem with redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time im able to find solution

I solved the issue with a property setting of ScriptManager
Below an example to set the timeout to 10 hours

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" AsyncPostBackTimeOut="36000" runat="server" />
```

Here i found it
http://forums.asp.net/post/1470167.aspx (Thank you so much JST)

I hope it helps somebody.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an unhandled exception from the account-creating code, so that the `Response.Redirect()` line isn't executed at all?

If you set a breakpoint on that line, does the debugger stop there?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be getting a ThreadAbortException somewhere possibly due to the long running process.  Maybe put your redirect in a try block and see if there's any exception caught?

I know this is off topic, but instead of redirecting, you can show a popup div (lots of example on the web on how to do this) and stay in the same page.

Comment: When i use Response.redirect("URL",false). i didnt see the exception.. bt im not redirecting...